# How to pass a variable as JSON object key in Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to execute the `curl` command that take a variable as key in JSON body but the variable is not being replaced by the value due to which I am getting a error `400`:

```yaml
tasks:

- name: set source tag 
  uri:
    url: https://****/api/v2/source
    method: POST
    body: 
      tags: 
         "{{ ec2_tag_KubernetesCluster }}": true
         "{{ ec2_tag_Environment }}": true
         "{{ ec2_tag_aws_autoscaling_groupName }}": true
      sourceName: "{{ ec2_tag_hostname }}"
    body_format: "json"  
    headers:
      Content-Type: "application/json"
      Accept: "application/json"
```

Output:

```json
"changed": false,
"connection": "close",
"content": "{\"status\":{\"result\":\"ERROR\",\"message\":\"invalid tag: {{ ec2_tag_Environment }}\",\"code\":400}}",
"content_length": "91",
"content_type": "application/json",
"date": "Tue, 22 Jun 2021 11:24:33 GMT",
"elapsed": 0,
"invocation": {
    "module_args": {
        "attributes": null,
        "backup": null,
        "body": {
            "sourceName": "eks-****-2-2a-worker53",
            "tags": {
                "{{ ec2_tag_Environment }}": true,
                "{{ ec2_tag_KubernetesCluster }}": true,
                "{{ ec2_tag_aws_autoscaling_groupName }}": true
            }
        },
        "body_format": "json",
        "client_cert": null,
        "client_key": null,
        "content": null,
        "creates": null,
        "delimiter": null,
        "dest": null,
        "directory_mode": null,
        "follow": false,
        "follow_redirects": "safe",
        "force": false,
        "force_basic_auth": false,
        "group": null,
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json",
```

As you see the `ec2_tag_hostname` is replaced with variable value but `ec2_tag_Environment`, `ec2_tag_KubernetesCluster` and `ec2_tag_aws_autoscaling_groupName` are not getting replaced as these are keys of JSON object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YAML does not support dynamic keys in any circumstance that I'm aware of; you will want to move the interpolation up one level in order to achieve what you're after:

```yaml
    body: >-
      {{
      {
      "tags": {
         ec2_tag_KubernetesCluster: True,
         ec2_tag_Environment: True,
         ec2_tag_aws_autoscaling_groupName: True,
      },
      "sourceName": ec2_tag_hostname,
      }
      }}
    body_format: "json"
```

That works because unlike YAML, Python (and thus Jinja2) does support dynamic `dict` keys.