# Ansible variable isn't substituted for dictionary key, but it is for the dictionary value

Tags: python, dictionary, ansible, jinja2

I am trying to do key and value updates with a dictionary I have created, but *with variables* for each. I prompted the user for which key they want to update, and also for what value and stored them using set_fact.

Here is my applications dictionary

```
applications:
  office:
    nuspec:
      id: black
      version: blue
    chocolatey_install:
      softwareName: yellow
```

When I hardcode 'id' and attempt to update its value with a variable, all is well. See below:

```
- name: Setting new_chocolatey_parameter_value
  set_fact: new_chocolatey_parameter_value="rainbow"

- name: Change applications.office.nuspec.id to prompted value
  set_fact:
    applications: "{{ applications|combine({'office': {'nuspec': {'id': '{{ new_chocolatey_parameter_value }}'}}}, recursive=True) }}"
```

I get the output Id hope

```
ok: [localhost]

TASK [output applications] *****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "applications": {
        "office": {
            "chocolatey_install": {
                "softwareName": "yellow", 
            }, 
            "nuspec": {
                "id": "rainbow", 
                "version": "blue"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I *also* want to use a variable to update where 'id' is in order to update the applications dictionary. See below

```
- name: Setting new_chocolatey_parameter_value
  set_fact: new_chocolatey_parameter_value="rainbow"

- name: Setting selected_current_chocolatey_parameter
  set_fact: selected_current_chocolatey_parameter="id"        

- name: Change applications.office.nuspec.id to prompted value
  set_fact:
    applications: "{{ applications|combine({'office': {'nuspec': {'{{ selected_current_chocolatey_parameter }}': '{{ new_chocolatey_parameter_value }}'}}}, recursive=True) }}"
```

But as you can see below it literally placed in the dictionary a new entry with the key being

"{{ selected_current_chocolatey_parameter }}"

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "applications": {
        "office": {
            "chocolatey_install": {
                "softwareName": "yellow", 
            }, 
            "nuspec": {
                "id": "black", 
                "version": "blue", 
                "{{ selected_current_chocolatey_parameter }}": "rainbow"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I simply get the value of {{ selected_current_chocolatey_parameter }}, which is just 'id', to be substituted in my applications dictionary update code? I am trying to get the same as the output when 'id' is hardcoded, but instead using variable's values to accomplish this.

I have tried many permutations of single/double quotes and tried escape characters to no avail.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
"{{ applications|combine({'office': {'nuspec': {'%s': '%s'}}}, recursive=True) }}" % (selected_current_chocolatey_parameter, new_chocolatey_parameter_value)
```

Comment: There's no need to use string interpolation when already in a jinja2 context; python `dict`s allow variables as keys: `"{{ applications|combine({'office': {'nuspec': {selected_current_chocolatey_parameter: new_chocolatey_parameter_value}}}, recursive=True) }}"` -- almost this exact question was [already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68087020/225016); I guess they come in waves

Comment: You are my hero! Thank you for the help! I am an amateur at this, is there any reading you can recommend to get me started on understanding jinja2 syntax?