# Ansible: How to use Jinja2 variable as dynamic YAML key?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I would like to create a dynamic YAML key name for the HTTP header of `uri` module within the task.

**`playbook.yml`**

```yaml
- name: "Set variable"
  set_fact:
    ACCESS_TOKEN_TYPE: "TEST-TOKEN"

- name: Check API
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: "https://my-url.com"
    headers:
      "{{ ACCESS_TOKEN_TYPE }}": "my-token"
```

But the substitution doesn't work. It works, when I replace `"{{ ACCESS_TOKEN_TYPE }}"` with `"TEST-TOKEN"`.

The result content should be:

```yaml
headers:
  "TEST-TOKEN": "my-token"
```

Comment: Please note that your second task is not a valid Ansible task declaration and would result in an error before it's even executed because of indentation errors. So it's hard to know if that's the source of your problem as you are not providing the actual result you get. You should [edit] and make this a correct [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a look into the following similar Q&A about

> *[YAML does not support dynamic keys in any circumstance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68087020/6771046)*

and the following minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    ACCESS_TOKEN_TYPE: "TEST-TOKEN"

  tasks:

  - name: Check Example API
    ansible.builtin.uri:
      url: "https://example.com"
      method: GET
      headers: >-
        {{
          {
            ACCESS_TOKEN_TYPE: "my-token"
          }
        }}
      return_content: true
    register: result

  - debug:
      var: result
```

called via

```bash
ansible-playbook uri.yml -vvv # to get the invocation and module_args used
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Check Example API] *********************
task path: /home/user/test/uri.yml:12
ok: [localhost] => changed=false
...
  invocation:
    module_args:
      attributes: null
      body: null
      body_format: raw
      ca_path: null
      client_cert: null
      client_key: null
      creates: null
      dest: null
      follow_redirects: safe
      force: false
      force_basic_auth: false
      group: null
      headers:
        TEST-TOKEN: my-token
      http_agent: ansible-httpget
      method: GET
      mode: null
      owner: null
      remote_src: false
      removes: null
      return_content: true
      selevel: null
      serole: null
      setype: null
      seuser: null
      src: null
      status_code:
      - 200
      timeout: 30
      unix_socket: null
      unsafe_writes: false
      url: https://example.com
      url_password: null
      url_username: null
      use_gssapi: false
      use_proxy: true
      validate_certs: true
  last_modified: Thu, 17 Oct 2019 07:18:26 GMT
  msg: OK (2815 bytes)
  redirected: false
  server: ECS (dcb/7F83)
...
  status: 200
  url: https://example.com
  vary: Accept-Encoding
  x_cache: HIT

TASK [debug] *********************************
task path: /home/user/test/uri.yml:29
ok: [localhost] =>
  result:
...
    content: |-
      <!doctype html>
      <html>
      <head>
          <title>Example Domain</title>
...
      </head>

      <body>
      <div>
          <h1>Example Domain</h1>
          <p>This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this
          domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>
          <p><a href="https://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p>
      </div>
      </body>
...
```

and containing the requested dynamic token type

```yaml
      headers:
        TEST-TOKEN: my-token
```

**Some Documentation**

- [`ansible-playbook --verbose`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-playbook.html#cmdoption-ansible-playbook-v)

  > *Causes Ansible to print more debug messages.*

and in order to get

```yaml
  invocation:
    module_args:
```

for this example.

Answer (score 0):

Working with K8S has really put me off templating yaml, getting the indentation right is hit or miss, so keep in mind that yaml is a superset of json, you could achive the same with::

```
- name: Check API
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: "https://my-url.com"
    headers:  {{ headers }}
```

Where headers comes from your inventory as a dict defined as either yaml or json:

```
headers:
  test-token: my-token
```

Basically, use json inside yaml when the target is machine, not human.  json is a valid yaml.